# Quick Sort algorithm with two pointers

Tags: python, quicksort

Can you help me with this task? It's from R. Sedgewick's "Introduction INTRODUCTION ТО PROGRAMMING IN PYTHON Ап lnterdisciplinary Approach"

> Partitioning. Compose a function that sorts an array that is known to
>   have at most two different values. Hint: Maintain two pointers, one
>   starting at the left end and moving right, and the other starting at
>   the right end and moving left. Maintain the invariant that all
>   elements to the left of the left pointer are equal to the smaller of
>   the two values and all elements to the right of the right pointer are
>   equal to the larger of the two values.

So I came up with this but it doesn't work. Where am i wrong? I believe it's caused when two quickSort2 methods are called after each other (I added some comments there).

```
import sys      

def quickSort2(arr, left, right, n, direction):
    if n == 1:
        return
    if left > right:
        return
    if left == right:
        print ("left ")
        print([i for i in arr[len(arr)-n:left]])
        print ("right ")
        print([i for i in arr[left+1:len(arr)]])
        print ("pivot ")
        print(arr[left])

        quickSort2(arr, len(arr)-n, left-1, left-len(arr)+n, True) # Is this ok?
        quickSort2(arr, left+1, len(arr)-1, len(arr)-left-1, True) # Is this ok?

        return
    if direction:
        if arr[left] < arr[right]:
            quickSort2(arr, left+1, right, n, True)
        #elif arr[left] > arr[right]:
        else:
            arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
            quickSort2(arr, left, right-1, n,  False)
    else:
        if arr[left] < arr[right]:
            quickSort2(arr, left, right-1, n,  False)
        #elif arr[left] > arr[right]:
        else:
            arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
            quickSort2(arr, left+1, right, n, True)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    #array = [5,4,5,4]
    #array = [5,4,5,4,4,5,4]
    #array = [5,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,4]
    array = [5,4,4,1,7,4,3,8,3,1]

    quickSort2(array, 0, len(array) - 1, len(array),  True)
    for i in array: print (i, end = " ")
```

For instance for array = [5,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,4] it returns

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Do you want to implement the quicksort algorithm or the exercise you quoted? Because this is not the same thing.

Comment: I want to implement exercise. Sorry if it's unclear but I assumed it sounds like a quicksort hence the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not ask you to implement a quicksort algorithm, it just requires you to partition a list, that has as **at most two different values**. The important bit in the hint is:

> Maintain the invariant that all elements to the left of the left pointer are equal to the smaller of the two values and all elements to the right of the right pointer are equal to the larger of the two values.

That's what you don't guarantee with your algorithm. Let's look at your example case: What happens if the left and right indices both point at a `5` and your current direction is from right to left. This `if` clause would be executed:

```
arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
quickSort2(arr, left+1, right, n, True)
```

Thus you swap the values (which has no effect, since they are equal) and increment the `left` index by one. And here is the problem, you violated the invariant: There is a `5` to the left of the left pointer.

---

I suggest dropping the `direction`, since it's not needed and adding two new variables, the smaller and the larger value. By doing so, you always know whether you may move on, or whether the pointer should stay at its current index.

Also I renamed the function to `partition` as this fits the exercise better.

```
def partition(arr, smaller, larger, left, right, n):
    if left >= right:
        # the two pointers met, the array is partitioned
        return
    if arr[left] == smaller:
        # move left pointer to the right
        partition(arr, smaller, larger, left+1, right, n)
    elif arr[right] == larger:
        # move right pointer to the left
        partition(arr, smaller, larger, left, right-1, n)
    else:
        # when we find a larger on the left and a smaller on the right, we swap
        arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
        # and move both pointers forward
        partition(arr, smaller, larger, left+1, right-1, n)
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day and probably the next couple of days. Thanks a lot. I knew it wasn't supposed to be difficult and it wasn't but I've spent too much time doing this.

Comment: You can upvote and accept my answer, if it helped you.